# Как разместить кнопки в div

Tags: html, css

Как расположить кнопки так как на картинке
[image: Как]

Пробовал как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1145869/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-div) не получилось (делал `display:block` и `z-index:10`)

**HTML**

```css
body {
  background-color: #090909;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

header {
  background-color: #141414;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px #000000;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

.about_person {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.person_title {}

.personName {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #282828;
  margin: 0;
}

.personNickname {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: purple;
  margin: 0;
}

.person_info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.personImg {
  max-width: 40% width:100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  height: 100%;
}

.person_description {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 1%;
  color: #505050;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.person_description h3 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.person_description p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.person_links {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10%;
}

.person_links a {
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.person_links a:hover {
  background-color: #DA70D6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MyFirstSite_copy_4_4</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

  <header>
    <h2>Professional cs:go players</h2>
  </header>


  <div class="about_person">

    <div class="person_title">
      <h2 class="personName">Alexandr Kostylev</h2>
      <p class="personNickname">s1mple</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person_info">

      <img class="personImg" src="s1mple.jpg" alt="">

      <div class="person_description">
        <h3>About s1mple:</h3>
        <p>s1mple is a steamer and top1 HLTV and also he is the most popular cs:go player in the world</p>
        <p>Age: 25 years</p>
        <p>Team: Natus Vincere</p>
        <p>Role: AWP</p>
      </div>

      <div class="person_links">
        <a href="https://www.hltv.org/stats/players/7998/s1mple">HLTV</a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLyVaqx9Pezekijg0IF7NYA">YouTube</a>
        <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/officials1mple/">Steam</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`positon:absolute` и `margin-left:0` и `margin-top:0` решили проблемму

```css
.person_links {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 80%;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.person_links a {

padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 3%;
background-color: #6e006e;
border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

Материалы:https://youtu.be/heh1N3qltF8?list=PL3LQJkGQtzc5G7wIQfVqBMEprmTKZIaXf&t=2101

Comment: Ничего не решили, я в другом вашем вопросе сделал правильно))